# Speeding up webscraping with Nokogiri & Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm brand new to using Nokogiri and Ruby, so bear with me here. I wrote a script to access a bunch of different pages on a website, each of which contains some links, which I want to extract. It works as intended, but I was wondering if theres a faster, more efficient way of accomplishing this. As it stand, the **get_urls** method collects the name used for the url of the pages where the links are located, so it will get 'bitcoin', 'ethereum', etc, then in the **get_websites** method it puts that string into the url where the links are located and scrapes each page.

I'm wondering if the way I'm doing this is inefficient and if there is a better way to do it. It takes a fairly long time to run, but as I said, this is my first foray into web scraping so I'm not sure if that is normal.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

def get_urls    
  url               = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"
  document          = open(url)
  content           = document.read
  parsed_content    = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
  cointable         = parsed_content.css('.col-lg-10').css('.row').css('.col-xs-12').css('#currencies')

  cointable.css("tbody").css("tr").each do |row|
    currency_name   = row.css('.currency-name-container').inner_text
    currency_link   = row.css('.currency-name').css('.currency-symbol').css("a").first.values
    link_name       = currency_link[0].gsub("/currencies/", "").gsub("/","")
    $url_list << [link_name, currency_name]
  end
end

def get_websites
  $url_list.each do |url|
    coin_arr        = Array.new
    url_name        = url[0]
    coin_name       = url[1]
    url             = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/#{url_name}"
    document        = open(url)
    content         = document.read
    parsed_content  = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
    links           = parsed_content.css('.container').css('.list-unstyled')
    puts "Adding #{url_name}..."

    links.css("li").css("a").each do |row|
        website = row.first[1]
        website_name = row.inner_text
        coin_arr.push([website_name, website])
        CSV.open('crypto_websites.csv', 'a+') do |csv|
            csv << [coin_name, website_name, website]
        end
    end
    $list_of_sites[url_name] = coin_arr 
  end
end

$url_list = Array.new
$list_of_sites = {}
get_urls
get_websites
```

Comment: The bottleneck is the network so the only thing that will make it faster is concurrency, but that's not going to be fun to implement.

Comment: Coinmarketcap has an api `https://coinmarketcap.com/api/`. Are you looking for information not available there?